# Multiple IF in IF's in order clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Don't know if the title is spot on, as I can't come up with a better description. I'll try to clarify it here, but it's a little tricky.

I'm working on have a order system, with handles cases. Each case can be divided into stages, but not always. All so each case will at one point get a "In production" state. The "In production" state has 2 dates for cases without stages and 2 dates for cases with stages 
- one for a deadline when is should be in production and one for when it actually was put in production.

Now that gives me 4 dates I need to order my Query by.

My problem is, that cases "in production" should be order together, and cases not "in production" should be order together, no matter if it a case with stages or not. I just need to look at different fields depending on the case have stages or not.

How do I do that?

I'll try to make a image, to make it more understandable.

[image]
e21, e23, r532i and r571a is all dates, and should be ordered as dates.

Comment: instead of so much theory...please show an example schema, input and expected output.... *theories are boring to be honest*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple ifs for selecting and ordering. On large data volumes it might become inefficient, though.

Example:

```
select id, if( id < 2, if (id > 6, 7, 8), 4 ) 
from a 
order by if( id < 2, if (id > 6, 7, 8), 4 );

+----+------------------------------------+
| id | if( id < 2, if (id > 6, 7, 8), 4 ) |
+----+------------------------------------+
|  2 |                                  4 |
|  3 |                                  4 |
|  4 |                                  4 |
|  5 |                                  4 |
|  6 |                                  4 |
| 11 |                                  4 |
| 12 |                                  4 |
| 13 |                                  4 |
|  1 |                                  8 |
+----+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: With inspiration from your example, I made this:
`IF (e.e3 IS NULL, IF (o5.r571 != 1, o5.r532i, o5.r571a), IF (e.e22 != 1, e.e21, e.e23) ) ASC`
and it seems to Work, but I have one question on top of that.
It now returns this:
0000-00-00  
0000-00-00  
2014-02-15  
2014-03-04  

Can I put those 0000-00-00 records at the buttom, and still have an ascending sorting with the valid dates?

Comment: You can bracket your order by clause with an additional IFNULL(<your clause>, '2035-01-01'), so that for ordering a date in the future is used in case of NULL values.